# Replacing string fragments in MYSQL cells

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a lazy way I can quickly replace all instances of a word with an other, purely in MySQL?

```
UPDATE sports SET matchup = .....
```

for example replace Manchester United with Man Utd and Wolverhampton Wanderers with Wolves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) command:

```
UPDATE SPORTS
   SET matchup = REPLACE(matchup, 'Manchester United', 'Man Utd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE table SET column = "new_value" WHERE column = "old_value"
```

Which becomes:

```
UPDATE sports SET name = "Man Utd" WHERE name = "Manchester United"
```

Comment: the problem was that the name is only a part of the old cell